# cURL not showing the whole GET parameter with PHP

Tags: php, curl, encoding, get

This is the code I use for sending notifications to my app.

```
    include("connection.php");
    include("utils.php");

    $Info = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE iddata = ".$_GET["dataId"]));
    $ownerInfo = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dataUsers WHERE id = ".$dataInfo['id']));
    $data = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT dataUsers.id, dataUsers.token, data.idData, data.id FROM data INNER JOIN data ON data.iddata = '".$_GET["data"]."' AND data.id = dataUsers.id"))["token"];

    $datagOwnerDeviceToken = getDeviceTokenFromUserToken($dataOwnerToken);
    //call server where simplePush.php is located -ports opened-
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => "http://www.myserver.com/sendNotif.php?msg=hello guys&deviceToken=xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'whatever'
        ));

        $resp = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
```

The problem is that I receive the notification but instead of "Hello guys", I receive "Hello", that's to say, the string rips off when it founds a blank space. I think it could be due to the encoding but I don't really know how to make it work.

If I change the msg parameter to msg=helloguys I receive to whole string. So there's a problem with blank spaces.

Many thanks.

This is now the actual code:

```
$curl = curl_init();
```

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,

```
$url = "http://server.com/notifications.php?".http_build_query(array(
    'msg' => "hello this is ".$dataInfo["wastringText"],
    'deviceToken' => $dataOwnerDeviceToken
));
```

echo "This is my url: ".$url;
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'whatever'
    ));
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

Comment: it may to help you
$url = urlencode(YOUR_URL_STRING); 
CURLOPT_URL => $url

Comment: @SergeyBelyakov You should not use `urlencode()` on the whole URL, just each parameter.

Comment: Still having issues placing the code in the labels. Someone who edit?

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the space as `%20` or `+`. But it would be best to use `http_build_query` to encode the whole query string.

```
$url = "http://www.myserver.com/sendNotif.php?" . 
    http_build_query(array(
        'msg' => 'hello guys',
        'deviceToken' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'
    ));
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'whatever'
    ));
```

Comment: I'm testing it. Give me one minute.

Comment: Is there really a curl_build_query or is that a typo?

Comment: @Barmar I wasn't able to make it work. Now the notification doesn't arrive.

Comment: What do you see if you do `echo $url`?

Comment: @Barmar Maybe I could encode a variable that locate the whole string parameter. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: You can do `$params = http_build_query(array(...));` and then concatenate `$params` to the base URL. But it should work the same either way.

Comment: @Barmar Nothing. It's empty.

Comment: Are you getting any errors or warnings in your PHP log?

Comment: I don't see how it can be empty. Even if `http_build_query` returns nothing, it should concatenate that empty string to the base URL, and then `echo $url` will print it.

Comment: @Barmar I've post an answer with the code you provided me adapted to what I need